# AzureMissingResourceHttpError when copying a blob with requires_sync=True, unless the container is public

Tags: python, azure

I'd like to copy a blob from one private container to another private container, within the same storage account.

I've written code that uses BlockBlobService, initialised with the storage account name and account key.

I found this worked fine for a few days, but suddenly it is having trouble with the requires_sync option.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

blos = BlockBlobService("some-storage-account", "some-storage-key")

blos.copy_blob("some-target-container", "some-target-key", blos.make_blob_url("source-container", "source_key"), requires_sync=True)
```

This fails with

AzureMissingResourceHttpError: The specified resource does not exist. ErrorCode: CannotVerifyCopySource

```
blos.copy_blob("some-target-container", "some-target-key", blos.make_blob_url("source-container", "source_key"))
```

This succeeds fine.

I'm using Python2.7.

In python3, it says requires_sync is an unexpected keyword argument. I only need it to work in 2.7 for now.

EDIT: I've worked around the problem with -

```
wait = blos.copy_blob("some-target-container", "some-target-key", blos.make_blob_url("source-container", "source_key"))
while wait.status == 'pending':
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

EDIT: changed while wait.status != 'success' to while wait.status == 'pending'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to install the latest [azure-storage-blob 2.0.1](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/) package.

For this error "AzureMissingResourceHttpError: The specified resource does not exist.", you should use a public container as you mentioned, or add sasToken to the blob url(like https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/f22/gen2.JPG?sasToken).

I tested in python 3.7, it works fine with setting parameter `requires_sync=True`.

The code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

accountName="yy3"
accountKey="xxxx"

blobs = BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName,account_key=accountKey)

copySource="https://yy3.blob.core.windows.net/f22/gen2.JPG?sasToken"

blobs.copy_blob("aa1","copy_gen2.jpg",copySource,requires_sync=True)

print("completed")
```

Note that both the destination / source containers are private.

The results as below, the blob file is copied to the destination container:

[image]

And here is the source code of `copy_blob` method, and the `requires_sync` is a valid parameter.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it essential to deal with sasTokens when I have a storage key? I am creating the BlockBlobService with the container name and key as parameters. I'm not sure why I can access a private container without require_sync, but with require_sync I should need to create and use a sasToken as well. My version installed is 2.0.1, but it is on python2.7 (a requirement for the time being).

Comment: @themusicalduck, I go through the docs, and nothing about this situation(if require_sync=true, and container is private). But as per the test, we need the sasToken in the source_url if specify "require_sync=true" and container is private. Not sure if it's a bug, I have submitted an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/604) in azure storage sdk github page.

Comment: Great, thank you for doing that Ivan. As mentioned this worked fine for me at first, so I wonder if it's down to a change that Azure have made on their end. I'll make a mention of it on the issue.